# The color of an echo

Tags: javascript, terminal, echo

I am doing **javascript/jQuery** *terminal*. I need to change color of an **echo**. Example:

```
if (command == 'help') {
        term.echo("No, I won't help you");
    }
```

I want that echo in red color. How to do that? Any ideas?

**Thanks for answer**

Here is website with the project:

http://david.addagio.cz/birthday.php

And yes, I am using javascript, so it is echo in javascript, not PHP

Check out website

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: There are many add-ons for different terminals to modify colors. `echo` is utilized in `PHP`, not Javascript. And as far as your question goes, its more like "No, we don't know how to help you."

Comment: If this is command line related, and you want to change the colors of the text displayed to the terminal, refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this? There's also no jQuery code there. I guess you're using Node.js?

Comment: Petr Cihlar, please edit your question to fix its tags and clarify your situation. That is what the downvotes mean here since the question is not a good question if it's unclear what you're asking. And when a question is unclear, those here which can help you are unable to since they don't know what kind of help you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There several modules that uses [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to alter color (and style) of characters that are outputted to console. For example, you can use [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk). Here is how your code may looks like:

```
var chalk = require('chalk');
// Output a line of text in green
console.log(chalk.green('Follow the white rabbit'));
```